# What causes the failure to add vendor prefixes in this Bootstrap 5 Sass project?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5, scss-mixins

I am working on a project with **[Laravel 8](https://github.com/Ajax30/BraveCMS-2.0)** and **Bootstrap 5 SASS**.

I use Latavel Mix to compile all the SCSS files - including Bootstrap and custom styles - into one CSS file.

I was unpleasantly surprised to see that using the `border-radius` mixin does not add prefixes in the compiled CSS.

For example:

```
.some-class {
    @include border-radius(50%);
}
```

results in:

```
.some-class {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

instead of:

```
.some-class {
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

To fix that, I added my own mixin:

```
@mixin border-radius($top-left:$border-radius, $top-right:null, $bottom-right:null, $bottom-left:null){
  -webkit-border-radius: $top-left $top-right $bottom-right $bottom-left;
     -moz-border-radius: $top-left $top-right $bottom-right $bottom-left;
      -ms-border-radius: $top-left $top-right $bottom-right $bottom-left;
          border-radius: $top-left $top-right $bottom-right $bottom-left;  
}
```

#### The problem

For a reason I have been unable to understand, vendor prefixes are still not added.

#### Questions

1. What causes this problem?
2. What is the most reliable way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: The various prefixes are usually added in the CSS build process (see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/build-tools/#autoprefixer. How are you building your CSS file?

Comment: Why would you want those prefixes anyway? [They aren't needed.](https://caniuse.com/border-radius) Anyone still using IE8 should be banned from the internet.